# Meteor.http.call Client-side Results Undefined

Tags: ajax, meteor

Consuming Mashape Airbnb API:

The following sits inside the Clients->airbnb.js file. 
My Results are undefined. But using the same API, http://jsfiddle.net/ismaelc/FZ5vG/
works just fine.

```
  function getListings(place) {
  alert(place);
  Meteor.http.call("GET", "https://airbnb.p.mashape.com/s",
                  {params : {location:place},
                  headers : {"X-Mashape-Authorization":"ffnGO1suGtJEjqgz4n7ykeuCbDP1hexv"}},
                  function (error, result) {
                    $('#listings').html(EJSON.stringify(result.data));
                    console.log("Status: "+result.statusCode);
                    console.log("Content: "+result.statusCode);
                    console.log("data: "+EJSON.stringify(result.data));
                    console.log("error: "+error.message);
                  }
                );
}

Template.where.events ({
    'click #find': function(event){
      var place = $('#location').val();
      getListings(place);
    }
  });
```

My Google Chrome Web Developers Tool is giving me odd HTTP Response. 
IMG: Here https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnWPL.jpg

Also, I momentarily see my console.log and then it just disappears. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the network tab in the chrome dev kit, make sure its already open before you do the request and it should just add on and you can view its text content to find where its all going wrong.

[image]

The response tab should have the text it gets back:

[image]

Of note is just check your api you might need to use `params` (HTTP POST params) instead of `data` (JSON post in the body), e.g `{params : {location:place}`.

Comment: I tracked down the Airbnb Mashape API script that's firing. 

I also switched the "data" call to "params". But my response header looks like my preview (source code). 

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v3sR6.png

Comment: You have to fire off a request to airbnb first and then itll appear there, at that moment thats just the code being sent to your browser from the initial load

Comment: I am doing that but I did alert(result.data), it saying "undefined" after I click the button. see airbnb.meteor.com - Also the console.log is disappearing

Comment: the form might not be submitting properly, in your click event you also need a `event.preventDefault()` in your event handler if your event is 'submit:function(event,context) {...}` where event matches that first param on the event function

Comment: Your code is fine, its just more of a javascript thing, when submitting forms with javascript you always have to stop the the events bubbling and causing the form to submit the traditional get/post way so event.preventDefault() stops this so javascript can manually submit the form.